# Cannot define keys on type 'User' deriving from 'People'. Only the root type in the entity inheritance hierarchy can contain keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I am using Web API 2.2 project with OData4 package + Entity Framework 6.

I have a `User` class which inherits from `People` class. `People` class itself inherits from `Person` class.

```
[Table("People")]
public class People : Person
{ }

public class User: People
{
   [Key]
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("Anonymous")]
   public int AnonymousId { get; set; }
}
```

When I execute the code an exception is thrown in `WebApiConfig::Register` method on this line

```
config.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "ODataRoute",
        routePrefix: null,
        model: builder.GetEdmModel());
```

Error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.OData.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot define keys on type 'User' deriving from 'People'. Only the root type in the entity inheritance hierarchy can contain keys.

I have tried solution given at 
http://stack247.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/cannot-define-keys-on-type-deriving-from-only-root-type-in-entity-inheritance-hierarchy-can-contain-keys/

but it did not work.

I tried :

```
builder.EntityType<User>().DerivesFrom<People>();
builder.EntityType<People>().DerivesFrom<Element>();
```

Comment: Only `Person` can have a `[Key]` property. Side note: does it make sense to have a class like `People`. Note that one object of this class represents *a* people. Usually classes with plural names indicate design flaws.

Comment: I have a legacy database exposed via Entity framework.The model is having these relationships.Is there a way where i do not have to edit my model and the exception is not thrown either.

Comment: Well, remove `UserId` from all classes except the root of the inheritance tree (`Person` or `Element`?).

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold for the help initiated.The team responsible for the ORM has accepted their mistake and removed Key attribute in the child class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Gert we have removed key attribute from child class.
This has  resolved the problem.